# I have some problems with displaying Appirater and the next show

Tags: ios, iphone, appirater

When you click on the button I want to call Appirater evry time, but when I press Remind Me Later that must appeared again in 5 days. Help me what my problem?

```
Appirater setAppId:@"600544412"];
[Appirater setDaysUntilPrompt:0];
[Appirater setUsesUntilPrompt:0];
[Appirater setSignificantEventsUntilPrompt:5];
[Appirater setTimeBeforeReminding:-1];
[Appirater setDebug:NO];
[Appirater appLaunched:YES];
[Appirater setDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is set 
`[Appirater setTimeBeforeReminding:5];`

that sets it to 5 days if the user presses Remind Me later
if you read the Appirater.h file you can see what the various flags do